# Force redirect HTTP to HTTPS (Opencart v1.5.6.4)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart

So, am helping a guy to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS but keep on getting loop error when adding any of these in .htaccess.

```
ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80   
Or
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
Or 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
Or
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
Or
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =off
```

This is a shared hosting (if that even matters). This is the phpinfo file and am not too sure how I can use this via .htaccess like what [this guy suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29051748)

```
_SERVER["https_proxy"]
```

http://www.supawhip.com.au/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

In `.htaccess` try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
</IfModule>
```

also in `/config.php`

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.supawhip.com.au/');
// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.supawhip.com.au/');
```

and in `/admin/config.php`

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.supawhip.com.au/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'https://www.supawhip.com.au/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.supawhip.com.au/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.supawhip.com.au/');
```

Comment: Still not working and getting this. 

    `This page isn’t working`
     `supawhip.com.au redirected you too many times.`