# How to stop wordpress redirect loop for HTTPS

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

HTTPS is working and HTTP is working, but when I try to add the redirect of HTTP to HTTPS in .htaccess file, it gets caught in a redirect loop.

Here is apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite

        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite

        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /var/SSLs/somecert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/SSLs/somekey.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /var/SSLs/trust.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
# RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]



</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I uncomment the RewriteCond, then it gets caught in a loop. In Wordpress I've set the site and home url to https.

I also added the following to the wp-config.php which solved https not working previously:

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Appreciate any help.  Note that I replaced the actual domain with mysite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# I added these two lines for redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# (end of custom modifications)

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

you should check these helping links :

[Correctly switching between HTTP and HTTPS using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108706/correctly-switching-between-http-and-https-using-htaccess)

[Redirect Loop while redirecting all http requests to https using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328601/redirect-loop-while-redirecting-all-http-requests-to-https-using-htaccess/19722706)